# Best SQL\NoSQL solution for specified requirements?

Tags: sql, postgresql, nosql

there's a data set with around 6 millions of records. Each record has the same number of fields. There are 8 fields totally:

```
ID  Title  Color  Date1  Date2  Date3  Date4...
```

There should be a way to filter these records by title and all date fields (or, 'columns' in RDBMS terms).

The size of the data is not so huge, around few gigabytes. We don't have long text fields etc. (we got rid of them during architecture creation, so now we have only really important fields in the data set).

The backend reads & writes the data quite intensive. We would really like to speed up both reads\writes (and filtering by fields) as much as possible. Currently we're using Postgres and we like its reliability, but it seems it's not really fast. Yes, we did some tweaking and optimization, added indexes, installed it on 32GB RAM machine and set all necessary settings. In other words, it works, but I still believe it might be better. What we need is speed: filtering records by dates and titles should be fast, really fast. Data insertion might be slower. The backend filters all records that were not processed, process it, and sets the date flag (of the datetime when it was processed). There are around 50 backend 'workers' executed every 5-10 seconds, so the DB should be able to perform really fast. Also we do some DB iterations (kind of a map\reduce jobs), so the DB solution should be able to execute this kind of tasks (RDBMS are not really good here).

We don't have joins there, the data is already optimized for big data solutions. Only one 'big table'.

And we would like to run it on a single node, or on many small instances. The data is not really important. But we would like to avoid expensive solutions so we're looking for a SQL or NoSQL solution that will perform faster than Postgres on the same cheap hardware.

I remember I tried MongoDB about a year or two ago. From what I remember, filtering was not so quick that moment. Cassandra was better but I remember it was able to perform only small subset of filtering queries. Riak is good but only for a big cluster with many machines. This is my very basic experience, if you guys know that one of these solutions performs great please do write that. Or suggest another solution.

Thanks!

Comment: "The size of the data is not so huge, around few gigabytes." — that's tiny for Postgres. It can (and does) handle databases a thousand times larger without any performance problems. Stick to what you're currently using; just learn to use it better.

Answer (score 2):

I agree with Ryan above.  Stick with PostgreSQL.

You haven't described what your write load is actually like (are you updating a few records here and there, but with a lot of parallel queries?  Updating with a fewer number of parallel queries but a lot of rows updated at once, etc).  So I can't tell you what you need to do to get more speed.

However, based on your question and the things you say you have tried so far, I would recommend that you consider hiring a consultant to look at your db, look at your environment, etc. with fresh eyes and suggest improvements.  My guess is that you have a lot of stuff going on that could be optimized quite a bit and you will spend a lot less on such optimizations than you will switching to a new environment.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Denis, that you should stick with Postgres. From my experience, the relational databases when tuned correctly have incredibly fast results. Or put another way ... I've found it much harder to tune Mongo to get complex queries returning in 10ms or less than I have tuning SQL Server and MySQL.

Read this website http://use-the-index-luke.com/ for ideas on how to further tune. The guy also wrote a book that will likely be useful to you.

Like Denis said, the data size is not so big that it would be worth the price to start from scratch with a NoSQL solution.

Comment: As a note, vanilla PostgreSQL handles databases in the tens of TB in size, and with stuff like Postgres-XC or approaches like federated storage, you could potentially get many times that size.  Additionally I expect that eventually the major bottlenecks in large datasets will be addressed so I wouldn't consider size at all a factor here.